# Chutzpah - Module is not available

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I am trying to unit test some angular code using Jasmine and Chutzpah test runner.
I have a module with a lot of dependencies:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', '7minWorkout', 'WorkoutBuilder', 'mediaPlayer', 'ui.bootstrap', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages', 'ngResource']);
```

I tried to load the dependencies like this:

```
beforeEach
    (function(){
        angular.mock.module('ngRoute', []);
        angular.mock.module('ngSanitize', []);
        angular.mock.module('WorkoutBuilder', []);
        angular.mock.module('mediaPlayer', []);
        angular.mock.module('ui.bootstrap', []);
        angular.mock.module('LocalStorageModule', []);
        angular.mock.module('ngAnimate', []);
        angular.mock.module('ngMessages', []);
        angular.mock.module('ngResource', []);
        angular.mock.module('7minWorkout', []);
        module('app');
    });
```

When I try to run the unit test with Chutzpah, I get the following error:

** Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

I also tried to specify the dependencies like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
...
  module('app', [...... long list of dependencies])
})
```

Still no result.
I found some articles on karma test runner for this type of issue, but failed to find any for Chutzpah. Any ideas ?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you file a issue on the chutzpah github page with a minimal repro?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with module dependencies and found a solution. The dependencies are defined in separate js files, for example ngSanitize. So add them to the beginning of your test file like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js" />
```

You just have to mock your module as follows:

```
beforeEach
(function(){
    module('app');
});
```

Or a shorter version:

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In the beginning of my test file there were references in the next order:

`/// <reference path="../app/app.controller.js" />
/// <reference path="../app/app.module.js" />
/// <reference .........`

The error was because code in `app.controller.js` used module `'app'` before it was declared in `app.module.js`. To fix this I just put `app.module.js` before all other my .js references:

`/// <reference path="../app/app.module.js" />
/// <reference path="../app/app.controller.js" />
/// <reference .........`